# Appropriate statistical tools to use

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance

First-time poster here, so I apologize in advance for whatever I'm doing wrong in writing this question.

I have a list of items.  Each has an associated score, and a list of inputs.

item1: score 122, inputs: (input1, input3, input7)
item2: score 101, intputs: (input2, input3, input20, input30)
item3: score 9, inputs: (input1, input7)

I know a few things about this dataset:

1. Each item has one or more inputs.  Many, but not all inputs contribute to more than one item.
2. Each input has a (hidden) score of its own, and the final score of each item is the sum of scores of its inputs. (This isn't strictly true, there's a degree of randomness.  But I think I can ignore that aspect for now.)
3. Scores are non-negative.

I would like to figure out which inputs lead to the highest final scores, and I SUSPECT I can get this, using relatively standard statistical methods, by calculating one of two things:

1. The probable score of an input, with error bars, or...
2. The correlation between the presence of an input, and a high final score.

So, here's my question:

1. Is my suspicion correct?
2. If yes, can someone point me in the right direction for learning how to do one of those calculations?  Or just straight-up tell me what to do :-)
3. If no, what would be an appropriate method to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: Do you only have the 3 items above or do you have more??. this seems to fall under curve fitting to data. In that case you get a function that best fits the data, and you can then optimize  the function to obtain the input values that maximize it.  ie $\arg\max_{X}[\min_g\sum(\hat g(X) - g(X))^2]$

Comment: Thanks @Onyambu, I'll look into that!